# Best way to perform UInt32 additions in VB.NET that are supposed to overflow

Tags: vb.net, encryption

While trying to write the ARX part of the ChaCha20 encryption algorithm in VB.NET, I run in to the issue of overflow exceptions during the addition part.

There are many additions of UInt32 numbers in the algorithm, and numbers are supposed to overflow during addition, but in other parts of my code I want to catch these exceptions.

One way of dealing with this and avoid overflow exceptions completely is to interim-convert to UInt64 and then do the additions this way:

a = (a + b) mod 2^32

I won't get any overflows but this doesn't work with the circular bit rotations needed for an ARX algorithm as I'm now pushing bits in to the empty 32 bits in the 64 bits UInt.

This converting back and forth is making the algorithm slower, and per 512 bits data block we are going through 20 rounds of a set of calculations so performance of this part of the code is pretty important.

Is there a more elegant way to deal with this in VB.NET?

More info about the algorithm:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20

Thank you for sharing your insights!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn overflow checking off per compiled assembly:

[image]

So it means you can have a DLL where you do all your overflowing math, and that DLL project has this tickbox checked (overflow checking is off)..

..but your main project that needs to do math with overflowing ON, does NOT have this option set in its own compilation settings

Here my OverflowOff project is a DLL that has "remove checks" enabled. A method has provided int maxvalue overflowed to int minvalue, then the forms project that uses the DLL has crashed with overflow because its own compile settings are set to perform overflow checks:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Caius good to know that is the best option for VB.NET! Initially hoping there was a C#-like option with checked/unchecked but couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: So, to be clear: put all of the Uint32 calculations for ARX that should allow overflows without exceptions in it's own VB.Net project and enable the `[] Remove Integer overflow checks` setting in that project only.  Yes?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking.. You can even just make a project of basic math functions like `Public Shared Function Add(i1 as integer, i2 as integer) Return i1 + i2`, put it in a project called Overflowable, turn off OF checks and use instead of `+`. If you want to use C# you can use `unchecked` and compile the C# into a DLL you can refernce from VB. You can also use C# projects and VB in the same solution and the debugger will stepback and forth between them happily.. I just thought you wanted to do all your calc in VB too, and AFIAA VB can only turn off overflow checking per assembly

Comment: Yes I want to keep the encryption/decryption code VB.NET code but good to know that I can combine VB.NET and C# projects in the same solution I thought that was not possible.

Comment: @DotNETFan Also, it can be simpler to program an algorithm in C# if you don't have to keep remembering to change `^` to `Xor` where the material you're taking it from uses `^`.

Comment: Thank you for that tip Andrew I agree C# has quite a few advantages, unfortunately we need to port the code (with some changes) to TwinBasic because for Microsoft Office Addins TwinBasic will be superfast (no .net interop to slow things down!).