# Can ChaCha20 symmetric encryption be implemented in VB.NET even though it lacks circular bit rotation?

Tags: .net, vb.net, encryption, encryption-symmetric

After reading up on encryption algorithms and getting some really good advice from Maarten, I see that the ChaCha20 encryption algorithm has the potential to provide strong symmetric encryption AND good performance on older computers that lack specialized AES encryption/decryption instructions.

Is there a good example of VB.NET code that implements the ChaCha20 encryption algorithm in VB.NET?

VB.NET may not be ideal because it lacks a lot of specific instructions, for instance for circular bit rotation on unsigned integers (which are a key part of ChaCha20), so the question is can this algorithm still be implemented well in VB.NET?

Comment: It certainly can! VB is turing-complete, so it can do anything other languages can, maybe less efficiently or less readable than others, but still possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to write the ChaCha20 encryption algorithm in VB.NET, it seems that it will work quite well. Please see the code below.

There is no circular bit rotation for integers in VB.NET, but in the code you will find a solid workaround for achieving circular bit rotation.

I have added a test subroutine that tests the code against some official ChaCha20 test vectors you can find in the final spec [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc7539/).

PLEASE TAKE IN TO ACCOUNT THESE GUIDELINES BEFORE USING THIS CODE:

- It has not been assessed by encryption experts and may contain security issues, especially on older CPUs that are chock-full of Meltdown and Spectre-type security flaws as well as a whole bunch more security flaws.
- Feedback to improve the code and performance is more than welcome, you can use this code freely and unrestricted.
- Until this code is assessed by experience encryption algorithm developers, use it where you are looking for obfuscation rather than strong encryption. (it is likely to offer this already, but zero guarantees)
- Make sure you protect the key you use, never store it unencrypted.
- Never ever (ever ever ever) use the same Nonce + Counter combination twice. You need these to decrypt the information, no need to protect these from an adversary put all your efforts in to making sure your key is safe.
- The subs for Encrypting and Decrypting are exactly the same, as this is symmetric encryption (that is why the sub names contain EncDec in the name).

Don't forget to check the Remove integer overflow checks-checkbox, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68376929/best-way-to-perform-uint32-additions-in-vb-net-that-are-supposed-to-overflow) how to do so.

Enjoy and let me know what needs to be improved!

```
Sub ValidateChaCha20AlgorithmAgainstStandard()

    'See final spec for ChaCha20 with test vectors here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc7539/

    Dim Key As String
    Dim Nonce As String
    Dim Counter As UInt32
    Dim HowMany As UInt32

    'Final spec for two blocks!
    Key = "03020100-07060504-0b0a0908-0f0e0d0c-13121110-17161514-1b1a1918-1f1e1d1c"
    Nonce = "00000000-4a000000-00000000"
    Counter = 1
    HowMany = 2

    Dim KeyStream() As Byte

    KeyStream = ChaCha20_GenerateEncDecByteStream(Key, Nonce, Counter, HowMany)

    Dim KeyStreamOutputHexString As String

    KeyStreamOutputHexString = ByteArrayToString(KeyStream)

    Dim ValidatedKeyStreamOutput As String

    ValidatedKeyStreamOutput = "224f51f3401bd9e12fde276fb8631ded8c131f823d2c06e27e4fcaec9ef3cf788a3b0aa372600a92b57974cded2b9334794cba40c63e34cdea212c4cf07d41b769a6749f3f630f4122cafe28ec4dc47e26d4346d70b98c73f3e9c53ac40c5945398b6eda1a832c89c167eacd901d7e2bf363740373201aa188fbbce83991c4ed"

    Dim StringCompareThatMustFail As String

    StringCompareThatMustFail = "I will fail for sure!"

    If KeyStreamOutputHexString.Equals(StringCompareThatMustFail) = False Then Debug.Print("String compare works properly")
    If KeyStreamOutputHexString.Equals(StringCompareThatMustFail) = True Then Debug.Print("String compare has FAILED DO NOT TRUST this verification!!!")

    If KeyStreamOutputHexString.Equals(ValidatedKeyStreamOutput) = True Then Debug.Print("ChaCha20 algorithm has passed the validation check, output is 100% correct")
    If KeyStreamOutputHexString.Equals(ValidatedKeyStreamOutput) = False Then Debug.Print("ChaCha20 algorithm has FAILED the validation check do NOT USE the algorithm!!!")

    'Now we test the bytestream encoding!

    Dim PlainText As String
    Dim PlainByteStream As Byte()

    PlainText = "Ladies and Gentlemen of the class of '99: If I could offer you only one tip for the future, suncreen would be it."

    PlainByteStream = UTF8StringToBytes(PlainText)

    Dim EncryptedStream As Byte()
    Dim DecryptedStream As Byte()
    Dim DecryptedString As String

    EncryptedStream = ChaCha20_EncDecByteStream(PlainByteStream, KeyStream)
    DecryptedStream = ChaCha20_EncDecByteStream(EncryptedStream, KeyStream)
    DecryptedString = UTF8BytesToString(DecryptedStream)

    If DecryptedString.Equals(PlainText) = True Then Debug.Print("2dn ChaCha20 validation check passed, algorithm has SUCCESFULLY performed a full encryption/decryption round trip yielding exactly the source data!")

End Sub

Function ChaCha20_EncDecByteStream(StreamToEncDec() As Byte, KeyStream() As Byte) As Byte()

    Dim b As Byte
    Dim ProcessedStream As Byte()
    Dim LoopCounter As Integer


    ReDim ProcessedStream(StreamToEncDec.Length - 1)

    For LoopCounter = 0 To (StreamToEncDec.Length - 1)

        ProcessedStream(LoopCounter) = StreamToEncDec(LoopCounter) Xor KeyStream(LoopCounter)

    Next

    Return ProcessedStream

End Function

Function ChaCha20_GenerateEncDecByteStream(Key As String, Nonce As String, CounterStartPosition As UInt32, HowManyBlocks As UInt32) As Byte()

    'This function creates a bytestream with the ChaCha20 encryption algorithm that can be used for further processing
    'The stream is always in units of 64 bytes (512 bits).

    'The key and the nonce are Hexadecimal strings with every 8 Hex characters (32 bits) separated by a - for readability 'coz that is just very convenient to use :)

    Dim KeyStringArray() As String
    Dim NonceStringArray() As String

    KeyStringArray = Split(Key, "-")
    NonceStringArray = Split(Nonce, "-")

    Dim ChaChaStartBlock(15) As UInt32

    'See specified under https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7539
    ' The first four words (0-3) are constants: 0x61707865, 0x3320646e, 0x79622d32, 0x6b206574.

    'Here we set the constants
    ChaChaStartBlock(0) = &H61707865
    ChaChaStartBlock(1) = &H3320646E
    ChaChaStartBlock(2) = &H79622D32
    ChaChaStartBlock(3) = &H6B206574

    'Here we set the key
    ChaChaStartBlock(4) = CUInt("&H" & KeyStringArray(0))
    ChaChaStartBlock(5) = CUInt("&H" & KeyStringArray(1))
    ChaChaStartBlock(6) = CUInt("&H" & KeyStringArray(2))
    ChaChaStartBlock(7) = CUInt("&H" & KeyStringArray(3))
    ChaChaStartBlock(8) = CUInt("&H" & KeyStringArray(4))
    ChaChaStartBlock(9) = CUInt("&H" & KeyStringArray(5))
    ChaChaStartBlock(10) = CUInt("&H" & KeyStringArray(6))
    ChaChaStartBlock(11) = CUInt("&H" & KeyStringArray(7))

    'Here we set the initial counter position
    ChaChaStartBlock(12) = CounterStartPosition

    'Here we set the Nonce
    ChaChaStartBlock(13) = CUInt("&H" & NonceStringArray(0))
    ChaChaStartBlock(14) = CUInt("&H" & NonceStringArray(1))
    ChaChaStartBlock(15) = CUInt("&H" & NonceStringArray(2))

    Debug.Print("Start block:")
    Debug.Print(Hex(ChaChaStartBlock(0)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaStartBlock(1)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaStartBlock(2)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaStartBlock(3)))
    Debug.Print(Hex(ChaChaStartBlock(4)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaStartBlock(5)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaStartBlock(6)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaStartBlock(7)))
    Debug.Print(Hex(ChaChaStartBlock(8)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaStartBlock(9)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaStartBlock(10)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaStartBlock(11)))
    Debug.Print(Hex(ChaChaStartBlock(12)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaStartBlock(13)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaStartBlock(14)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaStartBlock(15)))

    'Now we create a byte array of the size we will need
    Dim ChaChaByteArray() As Byte

    ReDim ChaChaByteArray(HowManyBlocks * 64 - 1)

    Dim ByteArrayFillLoop As Integer
    Dim ChaChaResultBlock(15) As UInt32
    Dim InnerLoop As Integer
    Dim FourByteArray(3) As Byte
    Dim FourByteArrayReverseOrder(3) As Byte

    For ByteArrayFillLoop = 0 To (HowManyBlocks - 1)

        ChaChaStartBlock(12) = CounterStartPosition + ByteArrayFillLoop

        ChaChaResultBlock = ChaCha20_GenerateEncDecBlock(ChaChaStartBlock)

        Debug.Print("Result block:")
        Debug.Print(Hex(ChaChaResultBlock(0)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaResultBlock(1)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaResultBlock(2)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaResultBlock(3)))
        Debug.Print(Hex(ChaChaResultBlock(4)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaResultBlock(5)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaResultBlock(6)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaResultBlock(7)))
        Debug.Print(Hex(ChaChaResultBlock(8)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaResultBlock(9)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaResultBlock(10)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaResultBlock(11)))
        Debug.Print(Hex(ChaChaResultBlock(12)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaResultBlock(13)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaResultBlock(14)) & " " & Hex(ChaChaResultBlock(15)))

        'Here we copy the block into the byte array
        For InnerLoop = 0 To 15

            FourByteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(ChaChaResultBlock(InnerLoop))

            If BitConverter.IsLittleEndian = False Then
                FourByteArrayReverseOrder(0) = FourByteArray(3)
                FourByteArrayReverseOrder(1) = FourByteArray(2)
                FourByteArrayReverseOrder(2) = FourByteArray(1)
                FourByteArrayReverseOrder(3) = FourByteArray(0)

                FourByteArray = FourByteArrayReverseOrder
            End If

            Buffer.BlockCopy(FourByteArray, 0, ChaChaByteArray, ByteArrayFillLoop * 64 + InnerLoop * 4, 4)

        Next

    Next

    Return ChaChaByteArray

End Function

Function ChaCha20_GenerateEncDecBlock(CC20M As UInt32()) As UInt32()

    Dim M(15) As UInt32

    Array.Copy(CC20M, M, M.Length)

    Dim R10CTR As Integer

    For R10CTR = 1 To 10

        Call ChaCha20_QR(M(0), M(4), M(8), M(12))
        Call ChaCha20_QR(M(1), M(5), M(9), M(13))
        Call ChaCha20_QR(M(2), M(6), M(10), M(14))
        Call ChaCha20_QR(M(3), M(7), M(11), M(15))

        Call ChaCha20_QR(M(0), M(5), M(10), M(15))
        Call ChaCha20_QR(M(1), M(6), M(11), M(12))
        Call ChaCha20_QR(M(2), M(7), M(8), M(13))
        Call ChaCha20_QR(M(3), M(4), M(9), M(14))

    Next

    Dim CTR As Integer

    For CTR = 0 To 15
        M(CTR) = M(CTR) + CC20M(CTR)
    Next


    Return M

End Function

Sub ChaCha20_QR(ByRef a As UInt32, ByRef b As UInt32, ByRef c As UInt32, ByRef d As UInt32)

    a = a + b
    d = d Xor a
    d = d << 16 Or d >> 16


    c = c + d
    b = b Xor c
    b = b << 12 Or b >> 20

    a = a + b
    d = d Xor a
    d = d << 8 Or d >> 24

    c = c + d
    b = b Xor c
    b = b << 7 Or b >> 25

End Sub

Function ByteArrayToString(ba() As Byte) As String

    Dim hex As New StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2)
    Dim b As Byte

    For Each b In ba
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b)
    Next

    Return hex.ToString()

End Function

Private Function UTF8StringToBytes(
ByVal str As String) As Byte()

    Return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str)
End Function

Private Function UTF8BytesToString(
ByVal bytes() As Byte) As String

    Return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)
End Function
```

Comment: I have a version that fully complies with Option Explicit On (there are some issues going back and forth between signed and unsigned integers in the code above), let me know if you need that one.